# How can I switch my display language to English in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, language

I live in Israel and I bought Windows 7 Professional in Hebrew. I'd like to switch the language to English.

In Control Panel -> Region and Language I don't have any options to switch the display language to English because only Hebrew is installed. In Windows Update, there are no language updates. I have waited three days, and still no language update.

Any Ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The software is called ["Vistalizator"](http://www.froggie.sk/) legal and free to install and works perfectly I used it myself to change brother's laptop to Spanish, like a charm, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

According to this, only Ultimate and Enterprise editions can download the language packs.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972813

The link below has instructions on working around this limitation. It's fairly involved and requires some registry tampering. Not sure if you want to do that.

http://nw360.blogspot.com/2009/10/install-windows-7-language-pack-on.html

Comment: Hmm thanks, can I download the English language pack for free?

Comment: Generally no, MS requires that you have a license for Ultimate/Enterprise. You can upgrade your existing Windows 7 installation using Anytime Upgrade (cost is about the difference plus a small amount) if this is important to you.